# CDATA section in RSS not working - rometools

Tags: java, spring-mvc, rss, rome

I am using rometools for rss feeds. I am trying to use html tags inside cdata in content section of the RSS item. Here is my code:

```
public class RssView extends AbstractRssFeedView {
@Override
 protected List<com.rometools.rome.feed.rss.Item> buildFeedItems(Map<String, Object> map,
                                                                HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                                                HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws Exception {
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    Object ob = map.get("feeds");
    if (ob instanceof List){
        for(int i = 0; i < ((List<?>)ob).size(); i++){
            Object articleObj = ((List<?>) ob).get(i);

            Article article = (Article)articleObj;
            Item item = new Item();
            item.setTitle(article.getTitle());

            Guid guid = new Guid();
            guid.setValue(item.getLink());
            item.setGuid(guid);

            item.setPubDate(article.getCreatedTime());

            Description description = new Description();
            description.setValue(article.getDescrition());
            item.setDescription(description);

            Content content = new Content();
            content.setValue(buildContent(article));
            item.setContent(content);
            items.add(item);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
@Override
protected void buildFeedMetadata(Map<String, Object> model, Channel channel,
                                 HttpServletRequest request) {
    channel.setTitle("Article");
    channel.setLink("http://www.");
    channel.setDescription("desciprtion");
    channel.setLanguage("en-us");
}

private String buildContent(Article article) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("<![CDATA[" +
            "<!doctype html>\n]]>");

    return sb.toString();
}
```

The problem is that html tags inside cdata that aren't supposed to be escaped are being escape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do, is not possible with Rome a the moment. See this issue: https://github.com/rometools/rome/issues/280

Comment: Thanks! Can you suggest any other tool for that?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

```
channel.setDescription(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml11(getProblematicDescription()));
```

from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```